# Jquery - Assigning the position of one div with another when elements are hidden

Tags: jquery, element

I have two images with only one visible at a time. Both have the "draggable" effect assigned to them, it is functioning correctly and both images can be dragged around on the screen.

They also have the "explode" effect assigned to them and the code is configured so when you double click one image it explodes and the other (previously hidden) image appears. And vice versa. So in short, only one image is visible at a time and when you double click it the other then appears per an "explode" effect.

My problem is when I double click one image the appearing image doesn't appear in exactly the same spot as the previous image. It actually appears either in the upper left corner of the window or wherever it was previously dragged. I would like the appearing image to show in the same position as the previous image.

I have explored the "clone" and "position" elements and am not sure if these operate on hidden elements since I can't seem to get them to work (of course I might be doing something wrong).

I need a way to assign the position of one element to another even if the element is hidden. I am hoping there is a simple non convoluted way to do this.

Thanks.

Here is some code:
The images are called "robot" and "car"

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#car').draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var lastLeft = ui.helper.data('lastLeft') || 9999999;
        if (ui.offset.left < lastLeft) {
             // must be moving left
             $('#myImage').attr('src', 'leftCar.png');
        } else {
             // must be moving right (or vertically)
             $('#myImage').attr('src', 'rightCar.png');
        }
        ui.helper.data('lastLeft', ui.offset.left); // store the last position
    }
});












$("#car").dblclick(function () {
      $(this).hide("explode", 1000);
      $("#robot").show("explode", 1000);


});


$("#robot").hide();
$('#robot').draggable({});
$("#robot").dblclick(function () {
      $(this).hide("explode", 1000);
      $("#car").show("explode", 1000);


});
```

**HTML**

```
<body>




        <div id="car">  
<img id="myImage" src="leftCar.png" alt="" height="200" width="200" />
</div>


<div id="robot">
<img id="myImage" src="robot.png" alt="" height="200" width="200" />
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Could you please post some code we can check? In your case I think a working jsfiddle would be preferred.

Comment: Code added. I will attempt to get a jsfiddle instance working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two images and you want to show the other one on double click, but want them both to drag with each other then you should put them both in the same parent div and set that parent div to be draggable. Then the images will always be relative to that parent div (if you set the css appropriately).

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/fFvLW/